# Android autocomplete with SQLite LIKE works partially

Tags: android, sqlite, autocomplete, sql-like

I have a `Restaurants` table in my SQLite DB that have the following records

```
| Name   | Latin_Name |
+--------+------------+
| Манаки | Manaki     |
+--------+------------+
| Енрико | Enriko     |
+---------------------+
```

Now I'm doing the search like this:

From my fragment:

```
String selection = DBHelper.COL_NAME + " LIKE ? OR " +
                    DBHelper.COL_LATIN_NAME + " LIKE ?";

String[] selectionArgs = {"%"+term+"%", "%"+term+"%"};

CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), 
                               DatabaseContentProvider.REST_CONTENT_URI, 
                               columns, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

The content provider `query` method:

```
 public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    switch(URI_MATCHER.match(uri)){
        case REST_LIST:
            builder.setTables(DBHelper.REST_TABLE);
            break;
        case REST_ID:
            builder.appendWhere(DBHelper.COL_ID + " = "
                    + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
    }
    Cursor cursor = builder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
            null, null, sortOrder);


    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

    return cursor;
}
```

So pretty basic right? Now here comes the problem:

If the `term` that comes in is **`en`** I can see the *Enriko* restaurants among the others.

If I pass **`enri`** I can't see the *Enriko* as a result anymore.

Same goes for the *Manaki* restaurant I can see it until **`mana`** and after that (for **`manak`** term for ex) I can't see it in the results list.

I was debugging my ContentProvider and I realized that the cursor was empty, so the problem have to be at the database level, I guess.

Please help.

**UPDATE:**

Having the @laalto comments in mind I decided to do some test on the database. In the `onCreate()` method of my `SQLiteOpenHelper`I inserted only those two records in the table by hand and it worked.

Now the problem is that I have to insert 1300 records `onCreate()` from a `json` file shipped in the `assets` folder. Right now I'm parsing the `json` file create an `ArrayList<Restaurant>` then loop trough it and insert one record per object for all 1300 items.

That kind of insertion won't work with the SQLite `LIKE` method.

Are there any gotchas about this kind of populating the database?

Maybe I need to change file encoding (it is UTF-8 now) or maybe database's collation, or maybe `getString()` from `JSONObject` can be tweaked for the database?

Comment: How do you produce the `Latin_Name` that goes in the db? Thinking of the possibility that there are some chars there that are not visible but affect the `LIKE` matching.

Comment: When I run this query `SELECT * FROM Restaurants where Latin_name LIKE '%enri%'` in a desktop SQLite app I get the desired result.

Comment: Ok - you could check the SQL the builder produces. e.g. replace `builder.query()` with `builder.buildQuery()`, log the query string and query with `db.rawQuery()`.

Comment: I tried that an even run this query `SELECT * FROM Restaurants WHERE (Latin_Name LIKE 'enrik%')` with `rawQuery()` and still nothing

Comment: I don't have any new ideas, just suspecting the `Latin_Name` has something more than just plain ASCII chars. You can `replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")` to get the non-ascii removed.

Comment: I have used this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xuecs.sqlitemanager to run the same queries against my database and it did returned the desired results.

Comment: Can you provide an explanation why you think that: `That kind of insertion won't work with the SQLite LIKE method.` A query has no idea "how" data was inserted so I am totally curious...

Comment: @WarrenFaith I'm totally confused, this problem breaks every law of physics. I wrote that statement because I was thinking that the encoding of the file have something to do with the data that SQLite can handle. But afterwards I read somewhere that Android's SQLite comes with UTF-8 support. But still I'm very confused.

Comment: I have pretty much the same code and work with chinese characters, so we should be on the same utf boat. My filter works without any issues. Only differences are 1) i use a loadermanager instead of rawqueries 2)  i insert my data from the internet, not an asset. My guess would be, you're probably converting the byteArray of the json asset to String with something different than UTF-8. Could you show us that part of the code ? Maybe your SQLiteOpenHelper too while you're at it.

Comment: Can you try inlining the query without the selection args? String selection = DBHelper.COL_NAME + " LIKE '%" + term + "%' OR " +
                    DBHelper.COL_LATIN_NAME + " LIKE '%" + term + "%'"; and see what happens?

Comment: @BartoszFilipowicz I tried that and it didn't work. I currently got away with ORMLite. Su-auhwang I also thought that DB creation maybe was the problem, so I created it with ORMLite and then I tried my ContentProvider described above and it didn't worked again. But ORMLite approach works.

Comment: @djandreski Can you try checking the database on your device/emulator via sqlite3? You need root for that. adb shell -> cd data/data/com.your.app/databases -> sqlite3 name_of_your_db.db . The in sqlite console try executing "select * from rest_table where col_name like '%term%' OR col_latin_name like '%term%'" and see what it gives you

Answer (score 2):

If it's urgent, here a quick and dirty solution.

2.600 strings (1.300 cyrillic + 1.300 latin) are really few values to handle in memory: you can simply load all values from the SQLite with

```
select name, latin_name from restaurants
```

and then you can loop the result set in Java while searching for the matching string with a **String.contains** method. Just remember that **contains** method is case sensitive, so you should use something like this:

```
string1.toLowerCase().contains(string2.toLowerCase())
```

Answer (score 1):

sqlite documentation [link](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#binaryops)

```
The LIKE operator does a pattern matching comparison. The operand to the right of the LIKE
operator contains the pattern and the left hand operand contains the string to 
match against the pattern. A percent symbol ("%") in the LIKE pattern matches any
sequence of zero or more characters in the string. An underscore ("_") in the LIKE 
pattern matches any single character in the string. Any other character matches 
itself or its lower/upper case equivalent (i.e. case-insensitive matching). 
(A bug: SQLite only understands upper/lower case for ASCII characters by default. 
The LIKE operator is case sensitive by default for unicode characters that are
beyond the ASCII range. For example, the expression 'a' LIKE 'A' is TRUE but 'æ' LIKE 'Æ'   
is FALSE.)
```